# Chrome Extension: Detecting new day (day changed) in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I know there's not a event listener for a new day (or hour/minute, for that matter). But in my Chrome Extension, I need to know when a new day has started, and which means I'll have to use a setInterval function to find out when the day has changed. However, I'm not sure what to use for the interval value: 10 seconds, or 10 minutes? I'm worried about using up CPU & memory (constant setInterval calls), but I still want to know almost as soon as a new day starts. Any ideas as to what is the ideal way to handle this?

Comment: I would guess in 90% times new day will be detected during first script run as not many people keep their browser open at midnight, so interval isn't that important.

Comment: Actually, I just got an idea - on first script run, I would calculate (based on the current UTC time) how many milliseconds until a new day begins - and do the same thing every script run/new day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending how exact you want to be, the only way doing this is by setting an interval. You can set your precision to be whatever you want. 1min 5min 10min

Comment: For my purposes, and because my program will be used by many people in different timezones, I think it a good idea to use set interval.

Answer (score 5):

If you mean a new day for the **user**, you can set a single timeout when the page loads.

```
function setnewdaytimer(){
    if(window.newdaytimer) clearTimeout(newdaytimer);
    var now= new Date,
    tomorrow= new Date(now.getFullYear(), now.getMonth(), now.getDate()+1); 
    window.newdaytimer= setTimeout(newdayalarm, tomorrow-now);
}
function newdayalarm(){
    alert((new Date()).toLocaleTimeString());
}

window.onload=setnewdaytimer;
```